# Need a bat file or vbs that will create shortcuts for all files in a folder

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, desktop, shortcut

I am looking or a way that end users can have shortcuts to frequently used files  populated on their desktop.  The files are in a specific folder in a mapped drive that is asigned to each user (L:\Desktop) and I would like to have a script or bat file that when run would create a shortcut for each file in this folder on the desktop.

Ideally this would be included or added to a bat file I have that takes files saved to the desktop and dumps them into the server share for security.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Steal the sample code for [CreateShortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (first Google hit for "vbscript shortcut"):

```
 set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
 set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\Shortcut Script.lnk")
 oShellLink.TargetPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
 oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
 oShellLink.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+F"
 oShellLink.IconLocation = "notepad.exe, 0"
 oShellLink.Description = "Shortcut Script"
 oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop
 oShellLink.Save
 set oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\Microsoft Web Site.url")
 oUrlLink.TargetPath = "http://www.microsoft.com"
 oUrlLink.Save
```

and for the [Files collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz72a8c0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (first Google hit for "vbscript files", "vbscript files collection)):

```
   Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   'get the folder by giving its path
   Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
   Set fc = f.Files
   For Each f1 in fc
      s = s & f1.name 
      s = s & "<BR>"
   Next
```

study the articles carefully, lookup terms unknown to you, and weave the code into one script.